# NanoGallery2 how to get the image id

Tags: javascript, jquery, nanogallery

i'm using the NanoGallery2 library, and, I'd like to get the image ID, i don't have any idea how can i take this. My code:

```
<div id="ng2" data-nanogallery2>
  @foreach ($photos as $photo)
    <a id="{{ $photo->id }}" href="{{ asset('uploads/'.$photo->path) }}" data-ngThumb="{{ asset('uploads/'.$photo->path) }}"> {{ $photo->image_name }} </a>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

The @foreach are  from BladeLaravel.

[Here](https://nanogallery2.nanostudio.org/documentation.html), on the API documentation, have the itemSelected event, but i just can take the "title", like the Image Name.

If I do this:

```
$("#ng2").on( 'itemSelected.nanogallery2', writePhotoName );
function writePhotoName(e){
   items = $("#ng2").nanogallery2('itemsSelectedGet');
   console.log(items);
}
```

The result:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djMgB.jpg)

Well.. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GetID()` to retrieve the item (image or album) ID

```
item.GetID();
```

or :

```
items[n].GetID();
```

[EDIT]

For your use case, you have 2 possibilities:
- use the attribute `data-ngid` to set the internal ID

```
<div id="ng2" data-nanogallery2>
  @foreach ($photos as $photo)
    <a data-ngid="{{ $photo->id }}" href="{{ asset('uploads/'.$photo->path) }}" data-ngThumb="{{ asset('uploads/'.$photo->path) }}"> {{ $photo->image_name }} </a>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

and to retrieve the ID : `items[n].GetID()`
- or use the attribute `data-ngcustomData` to store custom data:

```
<div id="ng2" data-nanogallery2>
  @foreach ($photos as $photo)
    <a data-ngcustomData='{ "myID"="{{ $photo->id }}" }' href="{{ asset('uploads/'.$photo->path) }}" data-ngThumb="{{ asset('uploads/'.$photo->path) }}"> {{ $photo->image_name }} </a>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

and to retrieve the ID : `items[n].customData.myID`

See sample on [codenpen](https://codepen.io/Kris-B/pen/jBYYeo?editors=1010)

Comment: Nops :(
The printed ID is the NanoGallery Image ID, not my ID.

My image ID, is 12 `<a id='12' href="image.jpg" data-ngThumb="image.jpg"> Image Name </a>`

And the printed ID is something like 6, 4, 8.. this doesn't make sense for me :(

Comment: Hey @Kris_b I need to set select some images, i'm trying to do this `$('#ng2').nanogallery2('itemsSetSelectedValue', [10,11,44] , true);`
But i have this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'selected' on number '10'`. PS: 10,11,14 are the data-ngid of the images. Thanks man

Comment: Hey @Hermus , it should be an array of items, not an array of IDs

Comment: man, I got this in exactly 20 minutes hahahha, my bad, my mind are crazy. Thank you so much Kris